# How to copy the permissions of a file to another?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Say I have two files:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 webapp webapp   215 Jun 21  2012 index.php
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      58 Dec 17 11:02 patch.log
```

I would like to give `patch.log` the same permissions as `index.php`.

I can do it manually:

```
chown webapp:webapp patch.log
chmod 664 patch.log
```

But this should be part of a script, where I don't necessarily know what the exact permissions of `index.php` are.

**Is there a way to copy permissions of a given file to another file?**

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a file as a reference file for both chown and chmod

```
chown --reference=index.php patch.log
chmod --reference=index.php patch.log
```

It's all in the man pages btw

[chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)

> --reference=RFILE
>                 use RFILE’s owner and group rather than  specifying  OWNER:GROUP
>                 values

[chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

> --reference=RFILE
>                 use RFILE’s mode instead of MODE values

Comment: Interesting. Never seen that before. But if you can read octal permissions...

Comment: It's be really nice if GNU manpages specified when they added arguments/functionality outside of the POSIX standard. This works in GNU `chown` and `chmod`, but not in any other OSes.

Comment: @ChrisS: The question is tagged linux ;)

Answer (score 5):

If there's any possibility of extended ACLs on the files in question, it's better to use getfacl/setfacl:

```
getfacl index.php | setfacl --set-file=- patch.log
```